# MySQL Obtain Multiple Columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct, sql-like

how would one achieve the ability to select multiple columns that are similar in the statement below?  I'm using the DISTINCT MySQL for the body, which works fine... but I cannot obtain additional information (columns) that goes with it.  Any ideas would be appreciated, please let me know if you need more information from me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.body
FROM Posts T
   LEFT JOIN Posts T2 ON T.body != T2.body
WHERE T.body LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.body, '%')
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT T2.body
FROM Posts T
   LEFT JOIN Posts T2 ON T.body != T2.body
WHERE T.body LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.body, '%')
ORDER BY body;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding column that you want to select. for example

SELECT DISTINCT T.body, T.Column1, T.Column2
FROM Posts T
   LEFT JOIN Posts T2 ON T.body != T2.body
WHERE T.body LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.body, '%')
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT T2.body
FROM Posts T
   LEFT JOIN Posts T2 ON T.body != T2.body
WHERE T.body LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.body, '%')
ORDER BY body;"

Comment: I receive the following error with that statement, although it's close: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns ;  What should I do to correct this?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT T.body, T.IDPosts, T.latitude, T.longitude, T.post_date FROM Posts T LEFT JOIN Posts T2 ON T.body != T2.body WHERE T.body LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.body, '%') UNION SELECT DISTINCT T2.body FROM Posts T LEFT JOIN Posts T2 ON T.body != T2.body WHERE T.body LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.body, '%') ORDER BY body;

Comment: Try make the same number of columns on your first select to the your second select. I mean the columns that you select mus be equal.